# equivalent of mmcblk0 in windows

Tags: python, windows

I know that `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2` in linux, its equivalent in windows is drives like drive `C:\`, `D:\`, but what i can't get is the equivalent of `/dev/mmcblk0` in Windows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the object namespace's `\GLOBAL??` directory (used by the Windows API for DOS devices, in combination with the logon session's DOS device object directory), drive "C:" is a symbolic link to a volume device, for example, `\Device\HarddiskVolume2`. Another link to this volume is, for example, `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2`. The raw disk 0 is `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0`. Back in `\GLOBAL??` you'll find a link to this named `PhysicalDrive0`. From the Windows API, use `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` or `\\?\PhysicalDrive0`. You'll need to determine the physical drive number that corresponds to a given volume.

Comment: Thanks. That exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`mountvol`:

```
Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point.

MOUNTVOL [drive:]path VolumeName
MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /D
MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /L
MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /P
MOUNTVOL /R
MOUNTVOL /N
MOUNTVOL /E

    path        Specifies the existing NTFS directory where the mount
                point will reside.
    VolumeName  Specifies the volume name that is the target of the mount
                point.
    /D          Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory.
    /L          Lists the mounted volume name for the specified directory.
    /P          Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory,
                dismounts the volume, and makes the volume not mountable.
                You can make the volume mountable again by creating a volume
                mount point.
    /R          Removes volume mount point directories and registry settings
                for volumes that are no longer in the system.
    /N          Disables automatic mounting of new volumes.
    /E          Re-enables automatic mounting of new volumes.

Possible values for VolumeName along with current mount points are:

    \\?\Volume{ac453eb9-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\
        H:\

    \\?\Volume{ac453ebd-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\
        C:\

    \\?\Volume{f4fca246-4148-11e3-9bf3-001bfcce59b4}\
        I:\

    \\?\Volume{ac453eba-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\
        E:\

    \\?\Volume{ac453ebb-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\
        F:\

    \\?\Volume{ac453ebc-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\
        G:\

    \\?\Volume{ac453ec2-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\
        A:\

    \\?\Volume{3d9f2651-e688-11e3-9c3c-001bfcce608a}\
        D:\
```

Please notice that Windows operates on ID's of volumes, not names... like `ac453eb9-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963`.

Edit after comment:

For more human-readable but totally useless form use:

`wmic diskdrive list brief /format:list`

It will return something like this:

```
Caption=Intel Raid 0 Volume
DeviceID=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
Model=Intel Raid 0 Volume
Partitions=1
Size=119932807680


Caption=Seagate Backup+ Desk SCSI Disk Device
DeviceID=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2
Model=Seagate Backup+ Desk SCSI Disk Device
Partitions=1
Size=4000776192000


Caption=Intel Raid 0 Volume
DeviceID=\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Model=Intel Raid 0 Volume
Partitions=4
Size=1000226949120
```

Please note that Windows knows nothing about drives in Raid, except that they are in Raid... this is because Raid is managed by BIOS.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  The OP wants a device name that refers to the entire disk, not to individual volumes.

Comment: But Windows operates on drive id... even in boot you got only that id... nothing more! I didn't misunderstand the question... check out the output... it lists all letters, but some of them have the same id, as those drives have multiple partitions... first string before first `-` in id identifies partition, the rest of the string... drive... `E:` `F:` `G:` `H:` are same drive with id `4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963`

Comment: If you would like something more user-readable, just use command `wmic diskdrive list brief /format:list`

Comment: But how would you use `4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963` to access the disk?  The `wmic` command is more useful - `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` etc. is exactly what the OP needs.  (I'm not sure why you describe it as "totally useless".)

Comment: Now I don't understand... every windows tool that acts directly on physical drive needs the ID of drive like `4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963`, not some `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` that is totally fake naming

Comment: If you use `CreateFile` to open `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` you get a handle to the disk, in exactly the same way that `/dev/mmcblk0` works on Linux.  I've written a (simple) utility for cloning drives that works this way, so I know for a fact that it works.  I've just used WinObj to look at the device namespace on this machine, and I can't find any sign of a device that looks like `4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963`.  Perhaps you could clarify with an example of how you would use such an ID?

Comment: Volume GUID names such as ``\\?\Volume{ac453ebd-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}\``, like logical drive-letter names such as `C:`, are implemented as links to the volume device object in the native object namespace, such as ``\Device\HarddiskVolume2``. They're based directly on a volume ID number, the source of which varies depending on the filesystem. One use for them is to mount a volume in an NTFS folder (i.e. a junction mountpoint). Personally I prefer mounting in folders, but Windows doesn't support mount notifications if a volume isn't assigned a logical drive letter.

Comment: If you want to open a volume device, you'd open ``\\?\C:`` or ``\\?\Volume{ac453ebd-4148-11e3-9bf2-806e6f6e6963}``. However, the OP wants the disk device, not the volume that's on the disk (assuming the volume doesn't extend across multiple disks). Disks are referenced via the `\\?\PhysicalDrive[N]` symbolic links, which are typically links to a raw device located at `\Device\Harddisk[N]\DR[N]`. In the Windows API you can query the disk number(s) for a volume via the I/O control [`IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365194).

Comment: FYI, ``\\.\`` and ``\\?\`` are the prefixes used for DOS devices. The ``\\.\`` prefix is subject to runtime library path processing (e.g. handling `..`) and thus is limited to `MAX_PATH` characters, while ``\\?\`` is simply replaced with the ``\??\`` virtual DOS device directory in the object namespace, without any additional path processing, which allows paths up to about 32760 characters (plus or minus after reparsing symbolic links). Name lookup in the ``\??`` virtual directory checks in `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\[Logon_Session_ID]` and then `\GLOBAL??`.

Comment: I'm lost, sorry :-) Not sure now ... As far as I remember, in Windows Server 2003, `boot.ini` and `diskpart` used `GUID` for physical device references. To be honest, that was the last version of Windows that I used not for gaming. We had some Windows Server 2008 and 2012 machines, but those were so annoying that we moved to Debian with 99% of projects and halted one using DirectX.